# M2 - How to restrict magento default class is picking bootstrap css in custom theme?

Tags: magento2.3.4, bootstrap4

I am using bootstrap for home page cms blocks responsive purpose,

declared in app\design\frontend\zero_theme\theme\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml

Its affect my PDP image size, description section, relevant products alignment, how to handle this situation?

I need bootstrap for responsive design, but its affect my default magento alignment in custom theme?

Comment: you need it only in homepage?

Comment: I need bootstrap for design purpose to all the pages, but why it's collapse my products images.

Comment: Happened to me too in another project you'll have to create some custom Css for the PDP images, try being specific on the custom css for the image you're looking to set right and it will get it without the not raccomended "!important"